# Why is Django Postgres JSONField decoded differently depending on whether object is created or updated

Tags: django, postgresql

I have a model with a PostGRES JSONField:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField
# ... other imports ...

class Feature(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    # ... other fields ...
    meta = JSONField(default=dict)
```

And an importer command that either creates or updates features:

```
    my_meta = {
        'mykey': 'something',
    }
    feature = Feature.objects.filter(id=id).first()
    if feature is None:
        # The feature was not imported previously
        feature = Feature.objects.create(
            id=id,
            meta=my_meta,
        )
        print('CREATED FEATURE.META', feature.meta, feature.meta.__class__.__name__)
    else:
        # The feature was already imported above - update the existing feature with new metadata
        feature.meta = my_meta,
        feature.save()
        print('UPDATED FEATURE.META', feature.meta, feature.meta.__class__.__name__)
```

When running two different test cases, each creating one feature but testing the two branches of that 'if' statement, I get:

`CREATED FEATURE.META {'mykey': 'something'} dict`

`UPDATED FEATURE.META ({'mykey': 'something'},) tuple`

**THE QUESTION**

Why on earth is it decoding inside a tuple in that latter case?

**NOTES**

- Yes, my default is a callable (common issue ppl have with JSONField)
- No, I don't have `django-jsonfield` installed (which can cause weird incompatibilities with the native JSONField)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've left a comma at the end of line, right here:

```
        feature.meta = my_meta,
```

This causes creation of a tuple with one member instead of assigning that member directly to `meta`. Remember that commas can work differently depending on the context.

Comment: Oh my word. I went so deep on that completely obvious thing. Thanks @GwnBleidD, all solved. And this is why you always copy/paste code into SO instead of writing it out ;)